# C# Selenium closes immediately

Tags: c#, selenium

Chrome closes immediately after the session started.
here is my code

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/ncr");
```

Comment: Is that all there is?  Are not doing any interactions with the page?  If so, then it SHOULD exit.  What are you hoping to have this do?

Comment: @TimRoberts even if I make it click on an element it clicks on it then closes instantly I want the page to stay open after all actions are done

Comment: "using" will dispose after finished: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement  Which is good, you don't really want an orphaned driver hanging around.

Comment: Put a thread sleep at last line of the code, and it will not be closed automatically.

Comment: Or `Console.ReadLine()` if you are running this code from the command line.